# Одновременные правки вопросов: возможное решение

Tags: предложение, нытьё

Снова подниму эту <strike>многострадальную</strike> тему об одновременной правке сообщений. Такой вопрос, а можно ли эту проблему частично решить отображением какого-нибудь уведомления во время редактирования о том, что кто-то уже отправил правку?

Вряд ли это трудно технически, зато уменьшит среднюю <strike>боль</strike> лишнюю трату времени статистически вдвое.

К примеру, начал править большой текст с ошибками, ещё половину не прошёл, и вдруг тебе высвечивается окошко с таким текстом: "С великим прискорбием вынуждены уведомить Вас о том, что *некто* уже сделал свою правку. Можете не стараться зря."

Comment: Видимо, особенность редактора для пользователей с репутацией ниже 2000. У меня редактор открывается прямо на странице с вопросом, и когда приходит стандартное уведомление об изменении вопроса, выдается заметное оранжевое предупреждение.

Comment: @zRrr и зачем обделили... зато есть, куда расти. В погоне за виртуальными бонусами, ахах, думал, что избавился от них, когда как-то давно отказался от игр.

Comment: Обходной манёвр: откройте в другой вкладке вопрос, который вы правите на текущей вкладке, и время от времени обновляйте там страницу на предмет правок от других пользователей. P.S. Справились с играми и тут справитесь.